# pyAMF for GAE (Google App Engine), little help needed:

Tags: python, google-app-engine, web-applications, pyamf

```
# I need this behaviour:
# 1) check if the service from flash is included in the services array
# 2) if not, return false or an error | if yes, step 3
# 3) combine the rootPath('app.controllers') with the service name('sub1.sub2.sub3.function_name')
# 4) and then get the function('function_name') from the 'app.controllers.sub1.sub2.sub3.function_name' package
# 5) then run the function the way that would be done normally by pyAMF 

from app.controllers.users.login import login
from app.controllers.users.logout import logout
from app.controllers.profiles.edit import edit as profilesEdit
from app.controllers.profiles.new import new as profilesNew
from app.controllers.invitations.invite import invite as invitationsInvite
from app.controllers.invitations.uninvite import uninvite as invitationsUninvite

def main():  
  services = {
    'users.login': login,
    'users.logout': logout,
    'profiles.edit': profilesEdit,
    'profiles.new': profilesNew,
    'invitations.invite': invitationsInvite,
    'invitations.uninvite': invitationsUninvite
  }

  gateway = WebAppGateway(services, logger=logging, debug=True)
  application = webapp.WSGIApplication([('/', Init),
                                      ('/ajax', gateway)], debug=True)
  run_wsgi_app(application)
```

insted of this I would like:

```
def main():  
  services = [
    'users.login',
    'users.logout',
    'profiles.edit',
    'profiles.new',
    'invitations.invite',
    'invitations.uninvite',
    'sub1.sub2.sub3.function_name'
  ]
  rootPath = 'app.controllers'

  gateway = WebAppGateway(services, rootPath, logger=logging, debug=True)
  application = webapp.WSGIApplication([('/', Init),
                                      ('/ajax', gateway)], debug=True)
  run_wsgi_app(application)

# and then I would extend the WebAppGateway in some way to have this behaviour:
# 1) check if the service from flash is included in the services array
# 2) if not, return false or an error | if yes, step 3
# 3) combine the rootPath('app.controllers') with the service name('sub1.sub2.sub3.function_name')
# 4) and then get the function('function_name') from the 'app.controllers.sub1.sub2.sub3.function_name' package
# 5) then run the function the way that would be done normally by pyAMF
```

is this possible? thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved last night! thanks @njoyce

```
from pyamf.remoting.gateway.google import WebAppGateway
import logging

class TottysGateway(WebAppGateway):
def __init__(self, services_available, root_path, not_found_service, logger, debug):
    # override the contructor and then call the super
    self.services_available = services_available
    self.root_path = root_path
    self.not_found_service = not_found_service
    WebAppGateway.__init__(self, {}, logger=logging, debug=True)

def getServiceRequest(self, request, target):
    # override the original getServiceRequest method
    try:
        # try looking for the service in the services list
        return WebAppGateway.getServiceRequest(self, request, target)
    except:
        pass

    try:
        # don't know what it does but is an error for now
        service_func = self.router(target)
    except:
        if(target in self.services_available):
            # only if is an available service import it's module
            # so it doesn't access services that should be hidden
            try:
                module_path = self.root_path + '.' + target
                paths = target.rsplit('.')
                func_name = paths[len(paths) - 1]
                import_as = '_'.join(paths) + '_' + func_name
                import_string = "from "+module_path+" import "+func_name+' as service_func'
                exec import_string
            except:
                service_func = False

    if(not service_func):
        # if is not found load the default not found service
        module_path = self.rootPath + '.' + self.not_found_service
        import_string = "from "+module_path+" import "+func_name+' as service_func'

    # add the service loaded above
    assign_string = "self.addService(service_func, target)"
    exec assign_string

    return WebAppGateway.getServiceRequest(self, request, target)
```